# How may we show that $\int_{0}^{\infty}{e^x+e^{-x}-3\over (e^x+e^{-x})^2-1}\cdot \ln(x)\mathrm dx={\pi \ln(2)\over 3\sqrt{3}}?$

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals

Consider $(1)$

> $$\int_{0}^{\infty}{e^x+e^{-x}-3\over (e^x+e^{-x})^2-1}\cdot \ln(x)\mathrm dx={\pi \ln(2)\over 3\sqrt{3}}\tag1$$

**My try:**

$x=-\ln(t)$ then $(1)$ becomes

$$\int_{0}^{1}{t^2-3t+1\over 2t+1}\cdot{\ln(-\ln t)}\mathrm dt\tag2$$

Split $(2):$

$$\color{blue}{\int_{0}^{1}{\ln(-\ln t)}\mathrm dt}+\int_{0}^{1}{t^2-5t\over 2t+1}\cdot{\ln(-\ln t)}\mathrm dt\tag3$$

$$\color{blue}{\gamma}+\int_{0}^{1}{t^2-5t\over 2t+1}\cdot{\ln(-\ln t)}\mathrm dt\tag4$$

Where $\gamma$ is [Euler-Mascheroni Constant](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Euler-MascheroniConstant.html).

**How may we prove $(1)?$**

Comment: This looks to me like something that could be solved with [contour integration](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Methods_of_contour_integration).

Comment: Only real analysis proof I can get so far uses partial fractions and is quite ugly and involved

Comment: Hmm.. still can't find a better way than just splitting $$\int _1^{\infty}\left(\frac{2}{u^2+u+1}-\frac{1}{u^2-u+1}\right)\ln \left(\ln \left(u\right)\right)du$$... only problem is that things like the Gamma function come up in the "closed form" of each split integral. Not pretty... there must be symmetries here I am missing

Comment: Another form is $$\int _1^\infty\frac{2u-3}{4u^2-1}\frac{\ln \left(\cosh ^{-1}u\right)}{\sqrt{u^2-1}}du$$ which might be attackable by trig substitution

Comment: The integration can be performed as a contour integral along a $\mathsf{key\mbox{-}hole}$ which 'takes care' of the $\ln$-$\mathsf{Principal\ Branch}$. However, that is a $\mathsf{cumbersome\ task}$. I prefer the @mickep fine answer.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The factor $\ln x$ tells me that this is a Frullani integral, hidden with an integration by parts. Indeed (forget the constant)
$$
\int\frac{e^x+e^{-x}-3}{(e^x+e^{-x})^2-1}\,dx
=\frac{2}{\sqrt{3}}\biggl(\arctan\frac{1+2e^x}{\sqrt{3}}-\arctan\frac{1+2e^{2x}}{\sqrt{3}}\biggr).
$$
This primitive will cancel the logaritmic singularities at $0$ and $+\infty$, and you are left with the [Frullani integral](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/FrullanisIntegral.html)
$$
\begin{aligned}
\int_0^{+\infty}\frac{1}{x}\frac{2}{\sqrt{3}}&\biggl(\arctan\frac{1+2e^{2x}}{\sqrt{3}}-\arctan\frac{1+2e^{x}}{\sqrt{3}}\biggr)\,dx\\
&=\frac{2}{\sqrt{3}}\biggl(\arctan\frac{1+2e^{+\infty}}{\sqrt{3}}-\arctan\frac{1+2e^0}{\sqrt{3}}\biggr)\ln\frac{2}{1}\\
&=\frac{2}{\sqrt{3}}\Bigl(\frac{\pi}{2}-\frac{\pi}{3}\Bigr)\ln 2
=\frac{\pi\ln 2}{3\sqrt{3}}.
\end{aligned}
$$

Comment: FANTASTIC answer. Thank you for posting this +1

Comment: Thank you @BrevanEllefsen, I'm glad it worked out so smoothly.

Comment: +1. Quite neat. Any contour integral is a cumbersome task. I started it but I left when I get bored !!!.

Comment: Many thanks for the bounty!